Copy true results from InStr to new worksheet
I have written the code below that currently returns a message box value of "yes" for each row the word "Transfer" appears in column "G" in the "Logistics worksheet.  Instead of a message box to appear, I would like to copy the entire row and paste it to the next available row in the worksheet "Transfers". I have done most of these functions on their own (copy a row, paste to new worksheet, search a range), but for wahtever reason I cant figure out how to combine them together.
Sub Transfers()

Dim Myrange As Range

Set Myrange = Worksheets("Logistics").Range("G2:G500")

For Each Cell In Myrange
    If InStr(LCase(Cell.Value), LCase("TRANSFER")) <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "yes"
    
    End If
    Next Cell
End Sub

I have tried the below code but get an

"Application-defined or object-defined error"

Sub Transfers

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, j As Long
    Set Myrange = Worksheets("Logistics").Range("G2:G500")

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Logistics")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Transfers")
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each Cell In Myrange
        If InStr(LCase(Cell.Value), LCase("TRANSFER")) <> 0 Then
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
            ws1.Rows(j).EntireRow.Copy ws2.Range("A" & lastRow)
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub


If you use Option Explicit, the undeclared variable j would be flagged. Change ws1.Rows(j) to Cell. Btw, LCase("TRANSFER") can be simplified to just "transfer". lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row really needs to have the worksheet specified.

And it would be Cell.EntireRow.Copy ws2.Range("A" & lastRow)
